# Sorting top ten vendors and showing remained vendors as "other"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please consider a table of vendors having two columns: `VendorName` and `PayableAmount`

I'm looking for a query which returns top ten vendors sorted by `PayableAmount` descending and sum of other payable amounts as "other" in 11th row.

Obviously, `sum of PayableAmount` from `Vendors` table should be equal to `sum of PayableAmount` from `Query`.

Comment: It would be very nice if we could see what you've tried first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would perform the query you're looking for. Firstly extracting those in the top 10, then `UNION` ing that result with the higher ranked vendors, but calling those `'Other'`

```
WITH rank AS (SELECT
VendorName,
PayableAmount,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PayableAmount DESC) AS rn
FROM vendors)

SELECT VendorName,
rn,
PayableAmount
FROM
rank WHERE rn <= 10

UNION

SELECT VendorName, 11 AS rn, PayableAmount 
FROM
  (
  SELECT 'Other' AS VendorName,
  SUM(PayableAmount) AS PayableAmount
  FROM
  rank WHERE rn > 10
  ) X11

ORDER BY rn
```

This has been tested in SQLFiddle.

Comment: I executed this .the "Other" row is not 11th row because its, amount is greater then 9th and 10th vendor in my table.

Comment: Try with `ORDER BY PayableAmount DESC` at the end.

Comment: the "Other" row's payableAmount is not least amount. so we can not do it.

Comment: Edited, now the column RN is used to rank the data

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it's possible to do in one query:

```
declare @t table (
    Name varchar(50) primary key,
    Amount money not null
);

-- Dummy data
insert into @t (Name, Amount)
select top (20) sq.*
from (
select name, max(number) as [Amount]
from master.dbo.spt_values
where number between 100 and 100000
    and name is not null
group by name
) sq
order by newid();

-- The table itself, for verification
select * from @t order by Amount desc;

-- Actual query
select top (11)
    case when sq.RN > 10 then '<All others>' else sq.Name end as [VendorName],
    case
        when sq.RN > 10 then sum(sq.Amount) over(partition by case when sq.rn > 10 then 1 else 0 end)
        else sq.Amount
    end as [Value]
from (
    select t.Name, t.Amount, row_number() over(order by t.Amount desc) as [RN]
    from @t t
    ) sq
order by sq.RN;
```

It will even work on any SQL Server version starting with 2005. But, in real life, I would prefer to calculate these 2 parts separately and then `UNION` them.

Answer (score 0):

this is for the 11th row

i didnt check it

```
declare @i int
set @i=
(select sum(x.PayableAmount)
from
(select * from table
except
select top 10 *from table
order by PayableAmount desc) as x)

select 'another',@i
```